# how do I convert a pdf to a bitmap image in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, bitmap

Looking for solution to convert a specified page of a pdf file to a bitmap image.

Comment: I was just thinking about this and how it could be done wrapping imagemagick.

Comment: There is an open source wrapper from imagemagick in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in a previous project.  We used ImageMagick.NET which is  a wrapper of perhaps the greatest open source image manipulation API there is, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This might do the job:

```
http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/products.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

Download [PDFcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) from SourceForge.  It is open source, and has COM automation component, sample code in a variety of languages.  You can use the PDFcreator printer driver to save in a numerous graphics formats.

Comment: Universal Printer Driver also works great, if you want a commercial product to perform this function.  Its a little more flexible and better documented, and offers COM automation and examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer I worked on this component at Software Siglo XXI)*

If you don't want to mess with Ghostscript API and need a quick working solution to convert PDF documents to raster images (PNG, JPG, ...), you could use **Super Pdf2Image Converter .NET**. It's available for both 32 and 64 bit and is very cheap and effective.

You can take a look here: http://softwaresigloxxi.com/SuperPdf2ImageConverter.html

For instance, here's a sample code for converting:

```
// Instantiate the component
Pdf2ImageConverter p2i = new Pdf2ImageConverter(pdfPath);

// Get page count of a PDF file
int pages = p2i.GetPageCount();

// Get size of any page
int width, height;
p2i.GetPageSize(1, out width, out height);

// Convert any page of PDF to image file (preserving aspect ratio)
p2i.GetImage(outputImagePath, pageNumber, resolution, imageFormat);

// Or... convert any page of PDF to image (returns bitmap object)
Bitmap bm = p2i.GetImage(pageNumber, resolution, width, height, imageFormat);
```