# Convert PDF Documents to Image

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I convert a pdf to a bitmap image in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239490/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-to-a-bitmap-image-in-net)

Is there any free API available to convert PDF to image. No GhostView/Scrip or Adobe utility

because to use it I have to execute its utility etc, I am looking for dll which I can add in

my project as a reference and use it, without executing any uitility.

Or, any code by which I can read PDF and convert that to Image?

Thanks

Comment: @Insuyasha If its a duplicate, I dnt think you need to down vote the question, it will be better to answer the question and point it to original question

Comment: I didn't vote it down.  Just because I'm noting its a duplicate doesn't mean I gave a downvote.  And I disagree.  In any case, I disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [PDFLibNet](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewer-win32/downloads/list).
It's heavy but works like a charm.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/xpdf_csharp.aspx?msg=3154408) you can find an article on how to use that library.

Comment: Thanks! Marco! will it be possible to conert PDF to image using this?

Comment: @BreakHead: yes. With that library you can _extract_ an image from every page and do what you please with that. More: the page is rendered to zoom factor you please, so it's not scaled but it's drawn using vectorial objects. It works; it's not exactly friendly for some operation, but with some effort you can obtain great things with that!