# How can I convert a base64 pdf string to an Image in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, base64

I need to be able to convert a base64 pdf string to a base64 image string.  I have tried ImageMagick and Ghostscript to no avail.

I can't pass a path because the data is retrieved as a base64 pdf string.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I convert a pdf to a bitmap image in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239490/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-to-a-bitmap-image-in-net)

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for.  Need to be able to pass the base64 string or byte array to the object to convert, not a path.

Comment: another solution I could use is to find a way to display the base64 pdf string in a viewer in ie?

Comment: I would try 2 more steps: Save the base64 string as PDF file; Convert PDF file to Image file (with ImageMagick or Ghostscript); Convert image to base64 string;